# RXTX serial port write binary data at boot

Tags: java, linux, rxtx, slackware

I've beed into a strange problem today and can't find anything to solve it the right way. I have a Java program that is started with /etc/rc.d/rc.local on Slackware **12.1**. The program works perfectly. It have to send data on ttyS0 after some requests are made, but in the last installations I needed to send binary data instead of ASCII and this is not working for binary. When I restart the program by the shell, it works perfectly. It seems that there are environment variables or something that cause the RXTX library to enable or disable the canonical mode but can't find this and can't find any settings in RXTX to init serial port in the proper mode.

Thank you,

Alex.

**EDIT :**

I can simplify the question by asking : Where in Slackware are the serial port initialized to be used in ASCII mode by default? (In my case /etc/rc.d/rc.serial is mode 644 so not executed.

Comment: it may be from paths but it may be about permissions too. writing to ttyS0 need privileges.

Comment: The application run as root at boot and when I restart it from shell, it was previously working in ASCII mode, now the binary on send bad data on serial port but send something.